# Как реализовать кодирования и декодирования файлов?

Tags: c++

Я хочу кодировать файлы и считывать их в зависимости какой файл загружаю.

Пока только экспериментирую по сколько рабочего прототипа норм не придумал

Вот код я изменил 1 символ ASCII и сохранил файл отдельно

```
// ASCII (h) 104 - > 777
static constexpr int64_t ascii_encoding[] {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59 , 60,
    61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90,
    91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 777, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120,
    121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150,
    151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180,
    181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210,
    211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240,
    241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255
};

int main() {
  std::ifstream in("test.txt", std::ios::binary); // внутри надпись > hhh hello hello world

  std::ofstream out("en_test2.txt", std::ios::binary);

  for (unsigned char c; in.get((char&)c);) {

    std::cout << (int)ascii_encoding[c] << " | " << c << " | " << (int)c << std::endl;

    //вариант 1 не работает на самом деле, оставил как пример
    //out.put((char)ascii_encoding[c]);

    //вариант 2 тоже работает криво
    //сохраняет но заполняет пустые значения нулями на каждый символ ascii + 7 нулей
    out.write((char*)&ascii_encoding[c], sizeof ascii_encoding[c]);

  }

  // еще тут должен был код декодирования данных с файла en_test2.txt в оригинал test.txt но я не сделал.
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: @ARHovsepyan нет это не задание для учеников, это я для себя делаю.
Возможно я не так написал вопрос, странно что вы так подумали

Comment: да, это как раз намек на то, что вы вопрос оформили не как вопрос...

Comment: Поправил заголовок

Comment: Мне написали

Этот код неверен в нескольких отношениях. По сути, вы не можете использовать массив кодирования для декодирования. Для этого вам нужна отдельная структура данных. encoding_array отображает байты в их закодированные значения. Если вы собираетесь декодировать, вам нужно что-то, что отображает закодированные значения в байты. Все наоборот.

Comment: вариантов кодировки в интернете думаю достаточно

Comment: @ARHovsepyan да там все ерунда

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1164302/398802

Answer (score 1):

`777` - это `9`, а кодирование должно быть однозначным. Так работать не будет, используй перестановку.

Comment: А перестановку это как?

Comment: @charlie, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation.

Comment: Капец сложно все :)